# ERROR (payload): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: javascript, express, payload, payload-cms

I followed the Uploads documentation that is provided on the Payload website to create a Media collection that allows for image uploads. That is working fine. My issue is that I am getting the following error whenever I try to use the uploaded images on a Page's block (Pages are also configured to a collection called Pages, with various blocks configured to the page):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

I have attached four images that will hopefully provide some context of the issue. The initial creation of a block that includes media works fine, however, I am unable to update or delete them after creation. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

UPDATE: I commented out the page blocks, and I am still seeing the error. I can't seem to find anything about the issue.[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPIts.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfxw8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4HYS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al2HT.png)

I was trying to created nested blocks that used images from the Media collection.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you